# Pass operand to function?

Tags: python, grammar, definition

Recent test question.  What gets passed to function?  I answered arguments.  Wrong answer.  Correct answer was operands.  Instructor insists that operands can be passed to function or procedure as well as arguments.  Is this valid?  I thought arguments were what was passed.  thanks,

Answer (score 1):

"Arguments" is the correct term for what is passed to a function.  An operand is one type of argument, generally associated with a particular operation, such as arithmetic computations.

Do you have more context for us, such as the full text of the question, and perhaps some context of the course?